# SQL Server query that determined oldest shipped date vs current inventory level

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to figure out how to write a T-SQL query to determine the following:

I have a table that contains shipment dates and quantities shipped for a particular item, and then a second table that has the current inventory in a store for that particular item.

My goal is to get the oldest shipped date based on the current quantity in the store, working my way from the newest to oldest. Example below:

Table #1:

```
Item    ShippedAmt  ShippedDate
-------------------------------
TESTITEM    45      3-Jul-2017
TESTITEM    13      22-Jul-2017
TESTITEM    77      3-Aug-2017
```

Table #2:

```
Store   Item        CurrentInventory
-------------------------------------
1234    TESTITEM    82
```

So in this example, we shipped 45 of TESTITEM on July 3, 13 on July 22, and 77 on August 3.

The current store inventory is 82 for that item.

Assuming that the 82 are from the newest shipments working backwards (they sell the oldest first), I'd want to be able to determine that the oldest "shipped date" in their store (in this case) is from July 22.

77 of the 82 items are from the August 3 shipment, and then the remaining 5 items are from the July 22 shipment. But the only detail I actually want to return is the oldest Shipped Date.

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a user defined function to calculate the shipping date based on an item and a quantity.  This may be useful if you need to reuse the calculation in several places.

Function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION uf_GetEarliestShippingDate (@itemName VARCHAR(100), @inventoryCount INT)
RETURNS DATETIME
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @Ret DATETIME = NULL
    DECLARE @MaxDate DATETIME = NULL
    DECLARE @Count INT = 0

    SELECT @Ret = MAX(ShippedDate),
        @Count = @Count + SUM(ShippedAmt)
    FROM Shipped
    WHERE item = @itemName 
    AND ShippedDate = (SELECT MAX(ShippedDate) FROM Shipped WHERE item = @itemName)

    WHILE @@ROWCOUNT > 0 AND @Count < @inventoryCount
    BEGIN
        --SELECT @Ret = @MaxDate
        SELECT @Ret = MAX(ShippedDate),
                @Count = @Count + SUM(ShippedAmt)
        FROM Shipped
        WHERE item = @itemName 
        AND ShippedDate = (SELECT MAX(ShippedDate) FROM Shipped WHERE item = @itemName AND ShippedDate < @Ret)
    END

    RETURN @Ret
END
GO
```

Usage:

```
SELECT *, dbo.uf_GetEarliestShippingDate(Item, currentinventory)
FROM inventory i
```

I've assumed Table 1 is called Shipped and Table 2 is called Inventory.

Comment: Thank you so much!! This is what I need :)

Comment: @jeniel You should mark this as the solution and/or upvote it as thanks.

Comment: Done! Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly, you can use cumulative sums:

```
select t1.item, min(t1.shippeddate)
from (select t1.*, sum(shippedamt) over (partition by item order by shippeddate desc) as cume_sa
      from t1
     ) t1 join
     t2
     on t1.item = t2.item
where t1.cume_sa - t1.shipped_amt < t2.currentinventory
group by item;
```

I'm not sure what `store` has to do with this problem.

Cumulative sums are available in SQL Server 2012+.  You can do something similar with `apply` or correlated subqueries in earlier versions:

```
select t1.item, min(t1.shippeddate)
from (select t1.*, tt1.cume_sa
      from t1 cross apply
           (select sum(tt1.shippedamt) as cume_sa
            from t1 tt1
            where tt1.item = t1.item and tt1.shippeddate >= t1.shippeddate)
     ) t1 join
     t2
     on t1.item = t2.item
where t1.cume_sa - t1.shipped_amt < t2.currentinventory
group by item;
```

Comment: I have changed your query to match my test table names and I'm getting a "Incorrect Syntax near 'order'" error message. Here's the exact query I used based on the one you've given me:

select testShipments.Item, min(testShipments.ShippedDate)
from (select testShipments.*, sum(ShippedAmt) over (order by ShippedDate desc) as cume_sa
      from testShipments
     ) testShipments join
     testStores
     on testShipments.Item = testStores.Item
where testShipments.cume_sa - testShipments.ShippedAmt < testStores.CurrentInventory
group by testShipments.Item;

Comment: @jeniel . . . You would seem to have an earlier version of SQL Server.  Have you seen the edit?  A user-defined function would not seem to be the best solution.

Comment: @GordonLinoff We are using SQL Server 2014.

Comment: @jeniel . . . Perhaps your compatibility level is set to 100 or less (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-database-transact-sql-compatibility-level).